# Rails production passenger cache?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, passenger

I am running production env on an Ubuntu Server 17.04, using passenger and Apache2.
Everything seems to work but the caching...

[image: Screenshot fo the menutext-class item]

The border was added when I was working on the menu - it since has been removed. As the code says:

[image: The sass file]

But in all browsers this code is visible:
[image: border]

That border code is not visible anywhere else than when I navigate to my production server. I have emptied the cache as best I can but it doesn't help.

I have restarted the passager instance no luck.
I even restarted the server... didn't help.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the assets folder from public directory and again run `rake assets:precompile`.